# How many configurations of tubes are there?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, configuration-spaces

Can $n$ disjoint lines in $\boldsymbol R^3$ be knotted? No... Let $X_n$ be the configuration space of $n$ disjoint lines in $\boldsymbol R^3$. It is not hard to see that $X_n$ is path connected: Let $L^1,...,L^n$ be $n$ disjoint lines. First wiggle them a little so that no two of them are parallel, and choose coordinates so that none of them are parallel to the $y-z$ plane. Parametrize $L^i=L^i_0$ as $s\mapsto (s, b_i + s\cdot v_i)$, where $b_i,v_i\in\boldsymbol R^2$. For each $t\in\boldsymbol R_{\geq 0}$ shift the $L$ to the left by $t$ units and squeeze by $1/(t+1)$ in the $y-z$ directions, so that $L^i_t$ is parametrized by $(s, (b_i+t\cdot v_i)/(t+1) + s\cdot (v_i/(t+1)))$. In the limit $t\mapsto\infty$, $L^i_{\infty}$ is parametrized by $s\mapsto (s,v_i)$, the lines are all parallel, and the problem reduces to path connectivity of the space of $n$ points in the plane. Fair enough.

What happens if the lines are thickened up a little? Let $Y_n$ be the configuration space of cylinders of radius 1 in $\boldsymbol R^3$. The obvious adaptation of the argument above fails because we aren't allowed to shrink the cylinders. Path connectivity of $X_n$ seems to depend on the fact that we can push whatever rats nest $L$ is arranged in out to infinity, but to do it the lines have to become arbitrarily close to one-another.

Questions: Is $Y_n$ connected? How many connected components does it have? I tried for a while to find a naive, combinatorial proof that $X_n$ is connected but everything I try implies connectivity of $Y_n$.

Comment: But you can "shrink" the cylinders, or do an equivalent action. Consider rhe axrs of the cylinders, cale up  the whole spacr applying that scaling to the axes.

Comment: Doesn't that push the tubes apart?

Comment: Yes it does, but then you have less troubles in makjng  them all parallel.

Comment: But you are going to push them to infinity like this, which will take you out of $X_n$ in the limit.

Comment: It seems to me that when you make some configuration of lines parallel, the infimum of distances between lines over the whole process is positive, no? So it works also with tubes of small enough radius, and you only need to perform the "shrinking" process -- pushing the tubes apart -- until this radius is reached.

Comment: In the parametrisation I gave the infimum goes to 0, but the points which are close are headed out to - infinity along the x axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof that $X_n$ is path-connected actually directly shows that $Y_n$ is path-connected. Suppose given $n$ disjoint cylinders in $\mathbb R^3$. Pick a plane which is not parallel to any of the cylinders. Now transform the cylinders by dilating their central axes away from the plane, so at time $t \in [0,\infty]$ the central axis of a cylinder is replaced by its dilation away from the plane by a factor of $t+1$. Because this dilation increases all distances, the cylinders stay disjoint. At $t = \infty$ each line is orthogonal to the plane, and we can use that the configuration space of $n$ discs in the plane is path-connected.

Comment: I think that's right. The original cylinders get stretched out into cylinders with cross section the intersection with the plane, which of course they fit inside.

Comment: Sorry, this is all really trivial after all.... In any case, what I am really wondering, I guess, is if there is a naive proof where you move them one-by-one, finitely many times. Scaling the space sort of cleverly evades the problem.